# Traveling through terminals CDG airport

Tags: airports, short-connections, cdg, connecting-flights

I'm arriving in CDG AIRPORT into terminal 2G, at 15.40 And need to make my flight in terminal in 1 at 17.05, Hoping that my flight is on-time, Is it possible to get a Taxi at Terminal 2G to take me to Terminal 1 and how long would this take? I'm aware that the transfer from terminals is 1 hour, Was hoping taxi ride would be faster?

Comment: The actual travel between 2 and 1 doesn't take that long, it's the getting in and out the terminals that makes it add up. That, combined with the risk of awful traffic makes me doubt that the taxi option makes sense.

Where are your flights going to and from? Are they on a single ticket?

Comment: Welcome to France. It will be very difficult to find a taxi willing to do this. Taxis at CDG have usually been waiting for hours before loading a customer and are therefore reluctant to short journeys (although it is not legal).

Comment: I was thinking of offering taxi €50 to get me to terminal 1 if it gets me there faster, I've booked both flights separate coming from Rennes and going to Dublin

Answer (score 3):

If I am no mistaken, Terminal 2G is a bit outside the terminal 2 , you have to take a bus to terminal 2F (or 2E), then there is an automated shuttle between terminals (one every 5 minutes).
So, to summarize, as stated above, you probably won't find a taxi:

1. leave the terminal to take the bus that will take you back to terminal 2E (the bus is just in front of the entrance if I recall correctly. anyway, it is easy to spot)
2. once inside, follow arrows to your next terminal (Terminal 1) . It should be written 'Terminal 1' or 'Shuttle'
3. hop on the shuttle, stop at terminal 1
4. find you way to your boarding gate (if your going up through a ramp, you are on the right track )
5. and once again, pass the security

Yes, sometimes we love to overcomplicate things :-p But it is less than one hour , you should be at the boarding gate before boarding begins

Comment: I was thinking of offering taxi €50 to get me to terminal 1 if it gets me there faster, I've booked both flights separate coming from Rennes and going to Dublin

Comment: nah, 50€ for that ? it's a rip-off. It is not complicated nor too long to go to the terminal 1 using free shuttles provided by the airport. Don't worry

Comment: @KD11 : so, how did it go ?